# How to present a window from an OSX Swift command line tool or shebang script file?

Tags: swift, macos, shebang

How to present a window from an OSX Swift command line tool or shebang script file?

Ideally, no additional files are used. No storyboard. No xib.

One example would be an OS X Command Line Tools Xcode project with a single Swift file.

```
import Cocoa // AppKit, CoreData, Foundation

let arguments = Process.arguments 

if (arguments.contains("usegui")) {
    // show arguments in a window with text field and dismiss button
    // GIVEN: some NSWindow
    let aTextField = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(25, 320, 180, 24))
    aTextField.stringValue = arguments.description
    let mask = NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask
    let aWindow = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 210), 
        styleMask: mask, 
        backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered, 
        `defer`: false)
    aWindow.contentView!.addSubview(aTextField)
    // add button ... 

    /* How to 
    * (a) present the window? 
    * (b) have window dismissed by user?
    */

} else {
    print("Using text IO here.")
    print(arguments)
}
```

Another example would be in a shebang Swift script.

```
#!/usr/bin/swift
import Cocoa // AppKit, CoreData, Foundation

let arguments = Process.arguments 

if (arguments.contains("usegui")) {
    // popup window showing arguments here
} else {
    print(arguments)
}
```

Background: Lot's of swift window examples exist in the context of an application.  And, many Swift REPL examples using text I/O.

Is there a reasonable way to popup an information window or request window from a swift CLI tool or swift script?

Comment: A workaround would be around the `osascript` command, but I'd like to know better answers.

Comment: @mouviciel Thanks. The puzzle is if Swift has become approachably sufficient, such that (hopefully) `osascript` and related `AppleScript` & `JXA` are not so much needed for CLI/Scripting with some GUI interaction.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I keep finding pieces of the puzzle, but haven’t gotten it to work yet.

Comment: @DanielWorthington I added  an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715691/how-to-present-a-window-from-an-osx-swift-command-line-tool-or-shebang-script-fi/48939057#48939057) regarding my findings and approach at this time.

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet found a solution as framed by the question. Setting up a window and handling the user interface events is non-trivial.

Apple provides a set of common user interactions (e.g. dialogs and alerts) in the [Open Scripting Architecture eXtensions (OSAX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript#Open_Scripting_Architecture).  Swift can call OSAX routines using `Process()` with the `launchPath` set to "/usr/bin/osascript".

```swift
let process = Process()
process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/osascript"
process.arguments = args // Applescript
// ... more code here ...
```

So, I ended up creating a framework named [`MCxSystemExecOsax`](https://github.com/marc-medley/MCxSystemExecOsax) which provides a set of Swift wrappers around many of the Open Scripting Architecture eXtensions (OSAX) user interaction features. A general run unix script is also included. [See `MCxSystemExecOsax` on GitHub for details.](https://github.com/marc-medley/MCxSystemExecOsax)

*It would be really interesting if a crossplatform user interaction library similar to OSAX existed. For example, such a library could likely be implemented with [Swift + Gnome Toolkit (GTK+)](https://github.com/search?l=&o=desc&q=gtk+language%3ASwift&s=updated&type=Repositories).*